# Single Transaction Getting Committed, Multiple transactions in a batch is remaining in PENDING State

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-sawtooth

I am running a hyperledger sawtooth network where the prod has 12 nodes while the tests we have 2 nodes. In test env whenever I am sending a batch with a single transaction, it's getting committed while, multiple transactions a batch remains in the PENDING state forever.

For the HTTP response, I am receiving 202 Accepted from Sawtooth.

The debug and error logs does not show any difference between the single and multiple transactions per batch.

I am using sawtooth golang SDK for development.

While the link below explains the possible scenarios,
https://github.com/danintel/sawtooth-faq/blob/master/client.rst#what-does-it-mean-if-a-batch-status-result-remains-pending

but this will not be applicable to my case since the batch with a single transaction is always getting successfully COMMITTED.

Anyone has any idea what can be the possible reason, and where can I at least look for the errors.

```
data": [
    {
      "id": "bb78d4b5e9cc0ec62b750a6ac0825dff816615d0a968584bc3fa0bfc31de82bc12a1961aa6f81f83b815ca38f2b252ca000a4324831c5c44c913a0a81a28f5b9",
      "invalid_transactions": [],
      "status": "PENDING"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Other possibilities for returning pending status, these transactions are waiting for dependencies to be resolved. In case of multiple transactions in a batch are you setting any dependencies?

Comment: No the there are no dependencies.

Comment: Do all the transactions in a batch belong to same TP? If not, then are all those TPs registered to the validator service?

Comment: Both are for different TP..one is custom one is IntegerKey and both are registered to the validator service

Comment: When you send one transaction in a batch, did you check it for both of them?

Comment: I have found this happening to me when there is some problem with any of my transaction in the TP and I am not properly handling it or throwing proper error. All following transactions goes to pending state and does not get processed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have debug in your Transaction Processor and is it enabled?  If so, are all transactions received and processed successfully and in the same order by your Transaction Processor?